# Is the connect method in the NPM mysql module blocking?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

The official mysql NPM package documentation for Node.js ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)) makes the following suggestion for connecting to a database and executing a basic query:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

The connect method also takes an optional callback function, and the documentation provides the following example of that usage (ignore the comments in the example below; this example is actually trying to demonstrate something else):

```
var connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
  port: 84943, // WRONG PORT 
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ECONNREFUSED' 
  console.log(err.fatal); // true 
});

connection.query('SELECT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
  console.log(error.code); // 'ECONNREFUSED' 
  console.log(error.fatal); // true 
});
```

In both cases, the query method is called after the connect method, and *not*, as might be expected, within the callback of the connect method.  This seems to imply that the connect method is blocking (ie/ synchronous).

So I have a simple question, followed by some more nuanced questions:

**Is the `connect` method in the NPM mysql module blocking?**

**If so, doesn't this go against the Node convention?** Wouldn't the convention be  to do a query within the callback passed to the `connect` method?

**Finally, if the connect method is blocking and does go against Node convention, why did the designers of the mysql module decide to make `connect` blocking? What are the advantages of this approach?** As the most popular mysql Node.js package, I'm sure there was a reason this approach was taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

From the documentation I'm inferring that all queries you perform are queued up internally.

When you call `connection.connect()`, it will (asynchronously) start setting up the connection to the server, and it'll also initialize a query queue where all queries that you want to run (by calling `connection.query()`) will get queued up.

Once the actual connection has been established, it will perform the queued-up queries.

Something similar happens with `connection.end()`: it will *"...make sure all previously enqueued queries are still [performed] before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server"* ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#terminating-connections)).

So it may *look* like both methods are blocking (synchronous), but in reality they aren't.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep! This make sense and seems like the likely explanation. Can someone authoritatively confirm?

Comment: You can always start looking through the source, for instance, [here is what `connection.query()`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/f98d2faaf386a646e011da874eb9b2a4a0f1f2e7/lib/Connection.js#L194-L209) does. The queue [is created and maintained in the protocol driver](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/f98d2faaf386a646e011da874eb9b2a4a0f1f2e7/lib/protocol/Protocol.js#L28).